# Get only today's stored document in Mongo DB

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm trying to get number of today's stored records in Mongo DB with PHP and for that I'm using below query:

> $todayCount =
>   $db->reviews->find(array('date'=>array('$gt'=>strtotime('today
>   midnight')),'b_id'=>new MongoId($b['_id'])))->count();

But its giving me 0. After analyzed the query found that its not giving any value. I spent enough time to resolve that but couldn't get any solution. Don't know where I'm doing it wrong.

I do have 2 today's records and when I tried to set static timestamp its giving me only one record and second is NULL.

Very confusing for me as I'm not much experienced with Mongo DB.

Comment: strtotime returns a UNIX-timestamp. Are you sure that's the type of your date-field in the database? (MongoDB recommends to use BSON Date for date-fields)

Comment: Thanks Philipp for your response. I just got the solution and I'm posting my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue. Actual issue was MongoDB $gt works for strings only and strtotime is returning integer and that was the reason I was getting null response from Mongo.

Solution is as below.

> $currentTime = (string)strtotime('today midnight');
>
> $todayCount =
>   $db->reviews->find(array('date'=>array('$gt'=>$currentTime,'b_id'=>new
>   MongoId($b['_id'])))->count();

It solves my issue. Please reply or add comment if anything needs to add.

Comment: it is not true that $gt works for strings only.  it works for all data types.  Your issue is that you are storing a string for your date (not a good idea to being with) and then are trying to compare it to a number.